# Can't send CoAP messages with Firefox-Copper plugin to other than local address(::1)

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I am trying to build up a CoAP network using RIOT-OS. I am working on Windows 7 64bit, using VMWare simulating an Ubuntu 14.04.2. The Network connection between the Guest and the Host is Nat: Share the host's IP address

I basicly copied the microcoap pkg and modified it to IPv6.I am using the Copper Firefox plugin (on the guest Ubuntu machine) to test if the client is working, and if I set the socket address to ::1 it works without a problem, but if I change it to anyithing else, which I want to, Copper can't seem to find it.
(BTW I am kind of new to network building, I never implemented one only read about them, and I just know this must be some trivial problem so excuse my noobness or if I provided too few information)

Copper can always connect to ::1 even if the CoAP client is not running, only if I try to issue a GET/POST or any other command, it says Network/Host is unreachable, but if I try some other Ipv6 address say fe80::20c:29ff:fe40:e46e/64 or fe80::20c:29ff:fe40:e46d/64 (which is the eth0's IPv6 address in this case) it immidietly says that Network/Host is unreachable.

(This is all data from the VMWare Guest Ubuntu, I don't think we need data from the Host Windows7 machine, but ofcoure I can provide it if you think that is where the problem is buried)

ifconfig:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 22:ba:7c:00:36:d6  
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20ba:7cff:fe00:36d6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:65 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:9367 (9.3 KB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:40:e4:6d  
          inet addr:192.168.159.130  Bcast:192.168.159.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe40:e46d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9828 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4668 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9443160 (9.4 MB)  TX bytes:542254 (542.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:117380 (117.3 KB)  TX bytes:117380 (117.3 KB)
```

At first I thought about the firewall, or routing problems, or Ipv6 forwarindg, but all seems allright.
The weird thing is that Wireshark that doesn't show anything if I try anything else than ::1, not even ICMPv6 or NDP, where at ::1 at least it shows the CoAP messages when I click on the GET or POST button.

net.IPv6.conf.all.forwarding is set to 1

ip6tables is empty and by default is set to ACCEPT

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

my ufw looks like this:

```
# /etc/default/ufw
#

# Set to yes to apply rules to support IPv6 (no means only IPv6 on loopback
# accepted). You will need to 'disable' and then 'enable' the firewall for
# the changes to take affect.
IPV6=yes

# Set the default input policy to ACCEPT, DROP, or REJECT. Please note that if
# you change this you will most likely want to adjust your rules.
DEFAULT_INPUT_POLICY="ACCEPT"

# Set the default output policy to ACCEPT, DROP, or REJECT. Please note that if
# you change this you will most likely want to adjust your rules.
DEFAULT_OUTPUT_POLICY="ACCEPT"

# Set the default forward policy to ACCEPT, DROP or REJECT.  Please note that
# if you change this you will most likely want to adjust your rules
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"

# Set the default application policy to ACCEPT, DROP, REJECT or SKIP. Please
# note that setting this to ACCEPT may be a security risk. See 'man ufw' for
# details
DEFAULT_APPLICATION_POLICY="SKIP"

# By default, ufw only touches its own chains. Set this to 'yes' to have ufw
# manage the built-in chains too. Warning: setting this to 'yes' will break
# non-ufw managed firewall rules
MANAGE_BUILTINS=no

#
# IPT backend
#
# only enable if using iptables backend
IPT_SYSCTL=/etc/ufw/sysctl.conf

# Extra connection tracking modules to load. Complete list can be found in
# net/netfilter/Kconfig of your kernel source. Some common modules:
# nf_conntrack_irc, nf_nat_irc: DCC (Direct Client to Client) support
# nf_conntrack_netbios_ns: NetBIOS (samba) client support
# nf_conntrack_pptp, nf_nat_pptp: PPTP over stateful firewall/NAT
# nf_conntrack_ftp, nf_nat_ftp: active FTP support
# nf_conntrack_tftp, nf_nat_tftp: TFTP support (server side)
IPT_MODULES="nf_conntrack_ftp nf_nat_ftp nf_conntrack_netbios_ns"
```

and my route -A inet6 like this(the aaaa::XXX and double fe80::/64 eth0 is just my experimenting, trying to make it work with other IP addresses):

```
Kernel IPv6 routing table
Destination                    Next Hop                   Flag Met Ref Use If
aaaa::212:7402:2:202/128       ::                         !n   1   0    12 lo
aaaa::212:7402:2:202/128       ::                         UH   1   0     0 eth0
fe80::20c:29ff:fe40:e46d/128   ::                         UH   1   0     0 eth0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    1   0     0 eth0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 docker0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1   412 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   3   117 lo
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
fe80::/128                     ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
fe80::20c:29ff:fe40:e46d/128   ::                         Un   0   1    79 lo
fe80::20ba:7cff:fe00:36d6/128  ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 0     0 docker0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1   412 lo
```

Here is the RIOT-OS code I am using, where the file descriptor and socket is created:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "shell.h"

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <strings.h>

#include "coap.h"

#define PORT 5683

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
    puts("Starting the RIOT\n");
    int fd;
    struct sockaddr_in6 servaddr, cliaddr;
    uint8_t buf[4096];//maybe need bigger becouse IPv6
    uint8_t scratch_raw[4096];
    coap_rw_buffer_t scratch_buf = {scratch_raw, sizeof(scratch_raw)};

    fd = socket(AF_INET6,SOCK_DGRAM,0);//Socket file descriptor init


    bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;//inet family
    servaddr.sin6_flowinfo = 0;//??

    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[0] = (uint8_t)0xfe;//IPv6 Address 1
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[1] = (uint8_t)0x80;
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[2] = (uint8_t)0x00;//IPv6 Address 2
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[3] = (uint8_t)0x00;
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[4] = (uint8_t)0x00;//IPv6 Address 3
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[5] = (uint8_t)0x00;
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[6] = (uint8_t)0x00;//IPv6 Address 4
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[7] = (uint8_t)0x00;
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[8] = (uint8_t)0x02;//IPv6 Address 5
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[9] = (uint8_t)0x0c;
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[10] = (uint8_t)0x29;//IPv6 Address 6
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[11] = (uint8_t)0xff;
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[12] = (uint8_t)0xfe;//IPv6 Address 7
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[13] = (uint8_t)0x40;
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[14] = (uint8_t)0xe4;//IPv6 Address 8
    servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr[15] = (uint8_t)0x6e;

    servaddr.sin6_port = htons(PORT);       //PORT (5683)
    bind(fd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    endpoint_setup();

    while(1)
    {
        int n, rc;
        socklen_t len = sizeof(cliaddr);
        coap_packet_t pkt;

        n = recvfrom(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, &len);
//#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("Received: ");
        coap_dump(buf, n, true);
        printf("\n");
//#endif

        if (0 != (rc = coap_parse(&pkt, buf, n)))
            printf("Bad packet rc=%d\n", rc);
        else
        {
            size_t rsplen = sizeof(buf);
            coap_packet_t rsppkt;
#ifdef DEBUG
            coap_dumpPacket(&pkt);
#endif
            coap_handle_req(&scratch_buf, &pkt, &rsppkt);

            if (0 != (rc = coap_build(buf, &rsplen, &rsppkt)))
                printf("coap_build failed rc=%d\n", rc);
            else
            {
#ifdef DEBUG
                printf("Sending: ");
                coap_dump(buf, rsplen, true);
                printf("\n");
#endif
#ifdef DEBUG
                coap_dumpPacket(&rsppkt);
#endif

                sendto(fd, buf, rsplen, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if I change servaddr.sin6_addr.s6_addr to ::1, it works, but ofcourse I want IPv6 addresses that were given by me to the clients.

Also, I can't seem to be abel to ping6 ipv6.google.com, though I can't ping it from the Host Windows 7 machine either, don't know why and don't know if it matters.

Later I'd like to create more than 1 client running at the same time, maybe connected through bridges, connectet to TAPs, running on 6lowpan, but right now I just want to make one device work.
(sry can't add wireshark pictures, no reputation yet to do that :< )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPv6 addresses in the fe80::/10 range are link-local addresses. The same link-local address range appears on every interface for a host. This presents a problem for the host if you try to use that address range to communicate since the host cannot know which interface to use. In most OSes, you must add a zone (interface) ID to the end of a link-local address in order to use it.  Some applications have a problem with this.

You should use a routable address.  The global address range is 2000::/3 (2001:2::/48 for benchmarking or 2001:db8::/32 for documentation are good candidates for testing, but they can't be used on the Internet).  The Unique Local address range is fc00::/7 (fd00::/8 in that range is available for local assignment with specific rules about pseudo random assignment), addresses this range can't be used on the Internet.

The best solution would be to get a range from your ISP and use that if you want to get out to the Internet to do things like ping Google.

Comment: Thanks, it works, I knew its something easy, though it only works if I give the global address to eth0, where I want to add these addresses to TAP devices, but I think I can figure that part out :)